# Why does this terrain (splat map) shader generate errors?

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, shader, metal

The shader below generates Metal errors when it samples the Texture Array. The code looks fine to me.

First, a Texture Array is declared(`UNITY_DECLARE_TEX2DARRAY(texArray)`), and later sampled (`UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY(texArray, float3(sPos...)`). For some reason, Metal seems to think that it's a texture, not a texture array.

[Running Unity 2019.1.8f1 on a MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid-2015, no GPU, Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB).]

Errors in console (many):
*Metal: Shader[Custom/Terrain]: Incompatible texture type [MTLTextureType2D] of texture bound at index 3, expected [MTLTextureType2DArray]*

```
Shader "Custom/Terrain" {
Properties {
    testTexture("Texture", 2D) = "white"{}
    testScale("Scale", Float) = 1
}
SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    LOD 200

    CGPROGRAM

    #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows
    #pragma target 3.0

    const static int maxLayerCount = 8;
    const static float epsilon = 1E-4;

    int layerCount;
    float3 baseColours[maxLayerCount];
    float baseStartHeights[maxLayerCount];
    float baseBlends[maxLayerCount];
    float baseColourStrength[maxLayerCount];
    float baseTextureScales[maxLayerCount];

    float minHeight;
    float maxHeight;

    sampler2D testTexture;
    float testScale;

    UNITY_DECLARE_TEX2DARRAY(texArray);

    struct Input {
        float3 worldPos;
        float3 worldNormal;
    };

    float inverseLerp(float a, float b, float value) {
        return saturate((value-a)/(b-a));
    }

    float3 triplanar(float3 pos, float scale, float3 axes, int index) {
        float3 sPos = pos / scale;

        // The following code is producing the error.
        float3 xProjection = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY(texArray, float3(sPos.y, sPos.z, index)) * axes.x;
        float3 yProjection = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY(texArray, float3(sPos.x, sPos.z, index)) * axes.y;
        float3 zProjection = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY(texArray, float3(sPos.x, sPos.y, index)) * axes.z;
        return xProjection + yProjection + zProjection;
    }

    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
         ...
     }

    }
    ENDCG
}
FallBack "Diffuse"
```

}

Comment: Haha, looks like you followed the Procedural Landmark Generation tutorial! A very good one, in my opinion :)

Answer (score 2):

You need also declare the array in the `Properties` section

```
texArray ("Tex", 2DArray) = "" {}
```

And the minimum shader model should be 3.5

```
#pragma target 3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The true solution for me:
Was to call CreateTerrain() while a modal scene was in full screen view waiting for the player.  Buy the time they finished up the modal actions, the terrain was nicely generated.

This was my old solution:

There is a race condition here.  To solve it I simply used Invoke and created the terrain 0.1 seconds later:

TerrainGenerator.cs

```
    void Start()
    {
        Invoke("CreateTerrain", 0.1f);
    }

    public void CreateTerrain()
    {
        textureSettings.ApplyToMaterial(mapMaterial);
        textureSettings.UpdateMeshHeights(mapMaterial, heightMapSettings.minHeight, heightMapSettings.maxHeight);

        float maxViewDst = detailLevels[detailLevels.Length - 1].visibleDstThreshold;
        meshWorldSize = meshSettings.meshWorldSize;
        chunksVisibleInViewDst = Mathf.RoundToInt(maxViewDst / meshWorldSize);

        UpdateVisibleChunks();
    }
```